# Referencing another cell and current cell in Google Sheets Conditional Formatting range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a column A which contains text values of two options: "One" or "Two". I have a series of columns (B:D) alongside which contain either the letter "A" or "B".

I want to create four conditional formatting rules over the range of columns B:D, and I want them to be coloured as such: a light green for instances of "A" if column A value is "One"; dark green for instances of "A" if column A value is "Two"; light red for instances of "B" if column A value is "One"; dark red for instances of "B" if column A value is "Two".

I have found a lot of info on referencing another cell's value in a conditional formatting formula, but I can't work out how to connect that to a cell where there is more than one value option, and how to expand that across a range of cells... any guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following custom formula in your Conditional Format rules:

**Range:** `B1:D`

**One - A [light green]:**  `=AND($A1="One",B1="A")`

**Two - A [dark green]:**  `=AND($A1="One",B1="B")`

**One - B [light red]:** `=AND($A1="Two",B1="A")`

**Two - B [dark red]:**  `=AND($A1="Two",B1="B")`

- You will notice, I used `$` in referencing `A1` which means that only the row number will increment and the column will be locked at Column A. While there is no `$` when I reference `B1` this means that both column and row index will increment based on the selected range.

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues during your implementation

Comment: Ron - this worked perfectly, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to hear that. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

Using color scales you can have multiple values.

[image]

[image]